# How can i reload TTLaucherView with new items?

Tags: ios, three20, ttlauncherview

I am using Three20 for my new iOS project. I have impletemented TTLauncherView & TTTabStrip, and both are displaying correctly. Now i want to load new items in TTLaucherView on selection of TTTabStrip.

How should i go about it ? I can't find any relevant method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty on this but looking at code from one of my apps, it looks like you add to the `self.launcherView.pages` collection (not sure if this is the default way of doing this, but in my project, `launcherView` is a class derived from `TTLauncherView`).

`self.launcherView.pages` is an `NSArray`, where each index is an array of `TTLauncherItem`s. So you add to an existing `page` or create a new `page`, and add `TTLauncherItem`s to it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

strange ! I was also looking for answer to same question. Currently i am creating new TTLauncherView whenever selection is changed for tab items.

But i am looking for a better solution.